# How to go through column based on input, and copy cell if input is found?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following problem.
[image: Example]

In the above, based on the input in column A, the script goes through column B and copies the content after the first dash ("-") until the next one in column C.

Example
2A-> goes through column B -> recognizes B3 -> copies after "-" until next "-" in 2C.

Comment: You can do this with a formula

Comment: Could you be so kind and tell me how this may be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office 365 put this in C2 and copy down:

```
=@FILTER(MID($B$2:$B$5,7,6),LEFT($B$2:$B$5,5)=A2)
```

If not O365 then:

```
=MID(INDEX($B$2:$B$5,MATCH(A2&"*",$B$2:$B$5,0)),7,6)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. I wish you all the best

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN TRY:

```
=MID(VLOOKUP(A2&"*",B:B,1,0),7,6)
```